# How do I remove black mold from area of laundry machine where water won’t reach?

Tags: mold, laundry

I noticed some black mold in my laundry machine. Unfortunately, this area seems to be in between the glass part and the plastic and I can’t fit even a fingernail in to remove it (even water can’t reach that spot when the machine is running as seen in the photo).

[image: As seen, the soapy water on the right does not reach the mold.]
As seen, the soapy water on the right does not reach the mold.

Is there a way I can remove the mold?

I’m doubtful conventional methods like bleach would work since there doesn’t seem to be any way for even water molecules to get through.

Comment: That is probably why the instructions for front loading washing machines tell you to leave the door open between washes.  I've found 25 percent bleach and water in a spray bottle kills mold after letting it sit for a few hours.

Comment: @ Steve Wellens Thank you very much. Yes, I try and leave it open until dry after use. Unfortunately, this mold was not by doing. Do you think the bleach/water solution will work if water can’t get in the crack?

Comment: The solution would have to touch the mold to work.  I wonder if the glass/gasket can be 'popped out'?

Comment: @Steve Wellens I took a look but it doesn’t look like it can unfortunately. There doesn’t seem to be any discernible bolts or anything that can be removed.

Comment: I would send that picture to the manufacture and ask how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of a comment than an answer, but I'm too new to comment :/

UV light would kill it, but you asked how to remove it so that doesn't completely answer your question...

And the EPA thinks that most home UV lamps won't do much.

https://www.epa.gov/indoor-air-quality-iaq/does-ultraviolet-uv-radiation-uv-lamps-kill-mold-0

Can you get it out into bright sunshine for a couple of days?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I don’t think I’ll be able to move it very easily (or replace it after).